# Opening Paint Shop Pro files in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, corel-paint-shop-pro

My colleague has Paint Shop Pro X2, I have Photoshop.  He tried saving a PSD version of a multi-layer image in PSP but, when I open the file in Photoshop, there's only a single background layer - the result of all the layers merged together.

I've tried a couple of plug-ins for for Photoshop that allows .pspimage files to be opened, but they just didn't work.

Is there a way he can save a single file that I can open in Photoshop, but with all the layers preserved?

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you save the file as .tiff it will preserve the layers.

Comment: I don't believe TIFF support layers.

Comment: You're right only TIFF images saved/opened in Photoshop preserve the layers.

Comment: That's a surprising omission. I haven't touched PSP in years, and never worked with it much, but I would have thought it sophisticated enough to save a layered tiff.

Comment: I actually don't have psp to test, but I tried opening a layered tiff in paint.net and it didn't preserve the layers. You could always try it with psp.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this is an issue with the originating software - is there a dialog or check box for including layers? Paint Shop Pro may not include layers by default.

Answer (score 0):

Paintshop Pro X2 was released in 2007. Most likely there will not be any easy solution. You could try to download a testversion of the current Paintshop version and export a new PSD file. Chances, that this will really work are not too good.